# Laravel php artisan config:cache throws Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. After installing new composer package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

My laravel project was working all fine in its development environment after including a php dependency `Shopify/shopify-php: ^0.11.0` and doing a php artisan config cache. Everything went fine until i pulled the same branch into a different directory and did a composer install for new dependency to reflect. Where following error came up on doing php artisan config:cache post install. And I have no clue where to start debugging it.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. 

in /home/apps/panel/v4.0.6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/apps/panel/v4.0.6/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(40): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('has', Array)
#1 /home/apps/panel/v4.0.6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(320): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /home/apps/panel/v4.0.6/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 /home/apps/panel/v4.0.6/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Here's my gitignore if that helps

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
public/.htaccess
```

Also checking out to a branch with the older dependencies, doing php artisan config:cache and returning to new branch and doing php artisan config:cache works fine.

Comment: Please provide laravel version.

Comment: The laravel version of my application is 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload` after `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Thanks James. I am unable to repeat the case right now as all the development environments have been updated. But I still dont understand the root cause of it.